how to use tls13-hkdf API of openddl3.0 to derived key?
How Do I Use the tls13-hkdf API of OpenSSL 3.0? In particular, how does it work with EVP_KDF_fetch? What does it mean to set libctx and properties to NULL when using EVP_KDF_fetch?
